# Приходит пустой body в POST запрос. NodeJS +EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

При отправке с клиента POST запроса с помощью fetch на сервер приходит пустой body, хотя на клиент данные с формы поступают, в чём проблема?

Файл сервера.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const User = require('./schemas/User');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Представления
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/')));
// CSS
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));
// JS
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));

app.post('/sign-up', (req, res) => {
    // const user = new User({
    //     name: req.body.name,
    //     lastname: req.body.lastname,
    //     patronymic: req.body.patronymic,
    //     email: req.body.email,
    //     password: req.body.password,
    //     phone: req.body.phone,
    // });
    //
    // await user.save().then(() => console.log(user));
    res.send(req.body.name);
});

// [index.ejs]
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Сервер работает');
});
```

Файл клиента

```
const formSignUp = document.querySelector('.form-sign-up');
    formSignUp.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(formSignUp.name.value);
        await fetch('/sign-up', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                name: formSignUp.name.value,
                lastname: formSignUp.lastname.value,
                patronymic: formSignUp.patronymic.value,
                email: formSignUp.email.value,
                password: formSignUp.password.value,
                phone: formSignUp.phone.value,
            },
        }).then(res => res.text()).then(data => console.log(data));
    });
```

Comment: Возможно, это то, что вам нужно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177049/express-js-req-body-undefined